# Is it ok (or bida') to recite these two dhikr in daily basis?

Tags: hadith, dua, muslim-practices, dhikr, fatwa-explanation

These following hadiths are part of morning and evening adhkar. And
it is prescribed to recite these in such a manner that the way the prophet (s.a.w) commanded us to recite. But I've came across something confusing context *(pdf, website's article, scholar's list which is actually authentic)* of morning and evening adhkar where I've found that in the both morning and evening adhkar section they put these following two dhikr **(when the text of those two dhikr clearly state that These can be recited *mentioned* {either in the morning or evening}  period)** also. I'm confused and at the same time afraid of failing into bida'(innovation) by reciting them regularly when our prophet (s.a.w) didn't do that. Please clarify and elaborate this poin☝️.
**Can I recite these two adhkar alone with the adhkar of morning and evening in daily basis?**

> 1/ Muslim (2709) narrated from Abu Hurayrah that he said: A man came
> ...https://sunnah.com/urn/517230....He(s.a.w) said: “If you had said,
> when **evening** came, A‘oodhu bi kalimaat-Illaah it-taammaati min
> sharri ma khalaq (I seek refuge in the perfect words of Allah from the
> evil of that which He has created), , it would not have harmed you.”
>
> 2/ Muslim (2726) narrated from Juwayriyah that
> ........https://sunnah.com/muslim:2726a...........He (s.a.w) came back
> in the **forenoon** said: “Are you still as you were when I left you?”
> She said: Yes. The Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him)
> said: “After I left you I said four words three times, which if they
> were weighed against what you have said today, they would outweigh it:
> ‘Subhaan Allahi wa bi hamdih ‘adada khalqihi wa rida nafsihi wa zinata
> ‘arshihi wa midaada kalimaatihi (Glory and praise be to Allah, as much
> as the number of His creation, as much as pleases Him, as much as the
> weight of His Throne and as much as the extent of His words)’.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assalamu A'laikum!

Both of the dua are from Authentic Hadith.

> **أَعُوذُ بِكَلِمَاتِ اللَّهِ التَّامَّاتِ مِنْ شَرِّ مَا خَلَقَ**

> **سُبْحَانَ اللَّهِ وَبِحَمْدِهِ عَدَدَ خَلْقِهِ وَرِضَا نَفْسِهِ وَزِنَةَ عَرْشِهِ وَمِدَادَ كَلِمَاتِهِ**

> You could recite both these Dua on a daily basis after Fajr Salah and Maghrib Salah as suggested by many scholars.

> The second Dua must be recited 3 times as mentioned in the Hadith and the first Dua can be recited 1 time or (better 3 times).

Also to my best knowledge
**you could recite the first dua 3 times or 1 time,**

1. if you stopover in anywhere in a journey or before sleep,
2. and if you feel unsafe or become afraid of anything (recite multiple times if needed)

and Allah (swt) knows best.

Jazakallahu khairan!